# why is it giving the error gets identifier not found in microsoft visual?

Tags: c, gets

The code is running in code blocks why its not runninng in visual studio 2015?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char name[20];
    char age[36];
    char sentence[40];

    puts("my name is");
    gets(name);

    puts("my age is");
    gets(age);

    strcat(sentence, "My name is ");
    strcat(sentence, name);
    strcat(sentence, " My age is ");
    strcat(sentence, age);

    puts(sentence);


    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide more details? Like the exact error. Your OS?

Comment: Check the size of array 'sentence' -> size should be 20+26+22 as per your usage (to handle max length of concatenated string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531344.aspx:

> - gets and _getws
>
> The gets and _getws functions have been removed. The gets function was
>   removed from the C Standard Library in C11 because it cannot be used
>   securely. The _getws function was a Microsoft extension that was
>   equivalent to gets but for wide strings. As alternatives to these
>   functions, consider use of fgets, fgetws, gets_s, and _getws_s.

And `strcat` wants a NUL-terminated string as destination, change to:

```
char sentence[40] = {0};
...
strcat(sentence, "My name is ");
```